# Asking a past professor to teach a workshop/short course

Tags: travel, workshop, fees

I would like to ask some of my former professors to come to my country and teach a small workshop, with undergraduate students, for a couple of days. I am doing this because I would like to raise the interest in my career, which is computer science, inside the faculty that I am currently working in. So the question that I have is: what would be the recommended things that I should offer to them, so that they are more likely to agree to pay a visit to my faculty? I ask this because I believe that I must submit like a report of expenses to my faculty dean or coordinator, so he or she could see if its feasible or not.

What expenses should my faculty cover? I was thinking of:

- Plane tickets
- Accommodation and meals
- Material for the workshop

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "workshop"? How many hours of lectures should the professor hold? What would be the audience? I'm asking because @aeismail and I seem to have understood different things...

Comment: I mean that the professor come and teach, in a basic way, some topic in which he/she is an expert. Only two hours per day and aimed to undergraduate students of my faculty.

Comment: @Layla: I think the term you're looking for then is a "short course," not a "workshop."

Answer (score 9):

In general, the expenses you've listed above (travel costs, local accommodations and meals) are typically sufficient. Registration fees for the workshop would also usually be waived.

One other thing you might consider offering, if funds are available, is a small stipend to be used by the faculty member to sponsor a "young researcher"—a graduate student or postdoc—who can also attend the workshop and take part, perhaps by offering a poster or contributed talk. (Or, if it is not possible to offer a stipend, perhaps the registration fees could be waived for the young researcher instead.)